# Externalizing a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

We are trying to externalize the array 'questions' below. What we have attempted is to copy-paste the array to an external javascript file we named "qList.js" and we tried including this in the  tag like so:
`<script src ="qList.js">`. Unfortunately this doesn't work. Any tips?

The code with the array included in the html is below (before externalizing just the array):

```
var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, chD, correct = 0; 

var questions = [
    ["Question 1", "Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3", "Choice4", "B"],
    ["Question 2", "Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3", "Choice4", "C"],
    ["Quesiton 3", "Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3", "Choice4", "A"]
];
function _(x) {
        return document.getElementById(x);
      }

function renderQuestion() {
    test = _("test");
    if (pos >= questions.length) {
      test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
     _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
     pos = 0;
     correct = 0;
     return false;
   }
   _("test_status").innerHTML = "Question " + (pos+1) + " of " + questions.length;
   question = questions[pos][0];
   chA = questions[pos][1];
   chB = questions[pos][2];
   chC = questions[pos][3];
   chD = questions[pos][4];
   test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";
   test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name = 'choices' value='A'> "+chA+"<br>";
   test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name = 'choices' value='B'> "+chB+"<br>";
   test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name = 'choices' value='C'> "+chC+"<br>";
   test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name = 'choices' value='D'> "+chD+"<br><br>";
   test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit</button>";
 }
 function checkAnswer(){
   choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
   for (var i=0; i<choices.length; i++) {
     if (choices[i].checked) {
       choice = choices[i].value;
     }
   }
     if(choice == questions[pos][5]) {
         correct++;
     }
       pos++;
       renderQuestion();
    }
      window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
    </script>
```

Comment: You need a closing `</script>` tag as well. But since you are not really describing what the issue is, it's hard to tell whether that is the only problem (or whether it is a problem at all). Please elaborate on "it doesn't work". What have you done so far to debug the issue?

Comment: Where did you put that tag? Please show the complete html markup, including both script tags.

Comment: Closing `</script>` appears to still be at the bottom of the code. If it's actually in the file, it'll break. Look at your developer console.

Comment: Yes, get rid of that closing tag. You also have some code that I assume you want executed at some point, that is not in a function. Maybe put all that into another function, and call that function at the point in the page you want it run.

Comment: "The code with the array included in the html is below", so I think he needs that `</script>`. The OP just hasn't provided the rest of the HTML for us to fathom what the problem is. OTOH, I don't see an opening `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track. Here's how to do it:

First, create that file **`qList.js`** and give it the values just as before:

```
var questions = [
    ["Question 1", "Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3", "Choice4", "B"],
    ["Question 2", "Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3", "Choice4", "C"],
    ["Quesiton 3", "Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3", "Choice4", "A"]
];
```

Now, import this file into your `.html` file BEFORE the rest of your JavaScript files, using this line:

`<script src="qList.js"></script>`

You may have had trouble with this because of the closing `</script>` tag, or that you had the script tag below the actual code that uses it.